# Running one web page across devices with the same data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple todo list web page for myself so that I can be a more organized person but I have a problem. I want to be able to close the website or switch to another computer and still keep the data of what I have done or not done on this to do list. I have tried to search up ways that I could do this online but I don't know what to search to find the right results.

I know about js and web design stuff but I don't know any back end stuff so.

Comment: Do some googling for "database driven websites howto".  You will need to host it on the internet somewhere in order to access it anywhere.  But bottom line is it needs to be hosted by a web site hosting provider and in order to keep track of items, you need some sort of place to save it, typically a database.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to upload your code to Github, which is a code management application for developers. Try searching on youtube how to navigate through GitHub and how to upload your code because im not that good with explanations just yet since im a beginner. Once your code has been uploaded, you can simply log into GitHub with the other device and open your code in a code base.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a solution to store its application data in (the data you create as a user), not the actual software code.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for telling me. Yes, you do need a database such as mongodb or firebase to store this information. look into node js and express to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of backend for what you are planing to accomplish. Such a backend could be a database storing each of your to-dos on a single database row, or some sort of file, which is located on a central server (the file could for example be a `.json`, `.xml` or `.csv`).

However, you can also write a JavaScript app, that stores your to-dos in your local browser storage, but then you would have to implement an export, import logic for a manual sync.

I assume that is not what you are looking for, so I would suggest checking out some services like for example the Google Drive API. You can interact with JavaScript with it and store your to-dos in your Google account: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js